# What causes DNS queries to be redirected to local router

Tags: dns

I'm trying to track down a problem.  Every once in a while I can't access the Internet because all DNS queries return my local router's IP address.

So, for example, everything resolves to 10.0.0.1

```
www.google.com => 10.0.0.1
cnn.com => 10.0.0.1
anything.com => 10.0.0.1
```

**Has anyone seen this problem before?**
**Do you know how to fix it?**

**Network Summary**

I have a COMCAST provided router/modem (10.0.0/24), and a 2nd firewall (10.1.2/24) [TP-LINK AC1750] that I've configured.  Both have had passwords changed.

**Observations**

My browser stops accessing the Internet because all DNS names resolve to my local COMCAST router.

When I try to access any site, I basically get a strange page that says I need to login to the network.  I've never clicked on anything because that might be what the malware wants me to click on.

After rebooting the TP-LINK router, the problem goes away, so I suspect there is someone hacking the TP-LINK router, but perhaps it is just a bug.

I've just upgraded to the TP-LINK AC1750 to the latest firmware version `1.0.14 Build 20200220 rel.33197(5553)` so perhaps that will help.

**Searches**

I've searched but not really sure what to look for.

- Googled `tp-link dns security issues` and got

-- https://techcrunch.com/2019/05/22/tp-link-routers-vulnerable-remote-hijack/ - Which says: *Thousands of vulnerable TP-Link routers at risk of remote hijack.  The exploit relies on the router’s default password to work, which many don’t change.*

-- https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/2278/ - Which says: *GhostDNS scans for the IP addresses of routers that use weak passwords or no password at all, accesses the routers’ settings, and then changes the default DNS address to the one controlled by the attackers*

Many other DNS attack issues were found.

Comment: You are assuming a security issue when it is likely a bug. Try searching for `tp-link dns issue` ...

Comment: "upgraded to the TP-LINK AC1750 to the latest firmware version" Do some more testing and get back to us.

Comment: are the clients using dhcp for the dns entry? if so, how is your dhcp configured (the dns entry)? how did you check the dns names get resolved to your routers's IP?